# Custom Metric In Tensorflow 2. Casting Y_true and Y_pred

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to implement a custom metric (F1 Score) for Tensorflow 2 sequential model. As a naive approach i created a function to accept y_true and y_pred and use SK learn to compute the result. I added this function in the Model Compile Metrices.

```py
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
def cust_f1_score(y_true,y_pred):
    print(type('Type Y_pred',y_pred))
    print(type('Type Y_true',y_true))
    print('Y_pred Shape',y_pred.shape)
    print('Y_true Shape',y_true.shape)
    print(y_pred)
    print(y_true)
    return f1_score(y_true,y_pred)

#Input layer
input_layer = Input(shape=(784,))
#Dense hidden layer
layer1 = Dense(50,activation='sigmoid',kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.glorot_normal(seed=30))(input_layer)
#output layer
output = Dense(10,activation='softmax',kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.glorot_normal(seed=0))(layer1)
#Creating a model
model = Model(inputs=input_layer,outputs=output)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.01)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy',cust_f1_score])#get_f1
model.fit(X_train,Y_train,epochs=2, validation_data=(X_test,Y_test), batch_size=16, )
```

I get the below output on shape and type information and the procedure fails and Sklearn does not get the right arrays

```
Type Y_pred <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
Type Y_true <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
Y_pred Shape (None, 10)
Y_true Shape (None, None)
Tensor("dense_71/Identity:0", shape=(None, 10), dtype=float32)
Tensor("dense_71_target:0", shape=(None, None), dtype=float32)
```

```
TypeError: Expected sequence or array-like, got
```

How to get the correct values for y_true and y_pred and use them? I know there are solutions using Keras Backend but they are not very intuitive.

Comment: Usually in this case, the format of the input data for training is incompatible with `Input`. Can you check the X_train and Y_train?

Answer (score -1):

Your error says,"TypeError: Expected sequence or array-like, got..."

your solution lies on proper reprocessing the y_true value, as you are getting output in shape of [None,10] ,(None, here represent batch), you should make sure your target sequence/array should be one hot encoded to length 10. you can use sklearn's LabelBinarizer for that purpose.